# unable to split the data in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to split my data in R using this-

```
Split <- sample.split(data, splitratio = 0.8)
```

but every time I get the following error-

```
Split <-sample.split(data, splitratio = 0.8)
```

> Error in sample.split(data, splitratio = 0.8) : unused argument (splitratio = 0.8)

Please let me know what this error means, is it something wrong with my data or the code is wrong?

Comment: Try : `Split <- caTools::sample.split(data, SplitRatio = 0.8)`

Comment: It must be case sensitive. It's SplitRatio , not splitratio.

Comment: @ Ronak....showing error caTools not found even though it is already installed

Comment: @Sang..tried with SplitRatio as well..not helping